# Retrieve the listview position of a row knowing the object inside the row (MergeAdapter)

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

i am trying to scroll a list to a known object inside the row of a listview. Problem is that i don't know how to retrieve that position if i know the object that is contained inside.

Part of the problem is that i use a `MergeAdapter` (Commonsware) for a list with headers and subheaders.

Any hints on how i could achieve this?

**THIS IS MY EDITED SOLUTION**

```
folder_list.setAdapter(all_adapter);
        if (itemToBeSynced != null) {
            int skip = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<all_adapter.getCount();i++){
                if(all_adapter.getItem(i)!=null && all_adapter.getItem(i) instanceof MileageReceiptInterface){
                    if(all_adapter.getItem(i).equals(itemToBeSynced)){
                        skip = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            final int finalSkip = skip;
            folder_list.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    folder_list.smoothScrollToPosition(finalSkip);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i get a class cast exception for this line

You indicated that you have "headers and subheaders", which this line does not take into account. Use the `instanceof` operator to see if the returned adapter is a `SyncItemAdapter`, and proceed with your cast and the rest of this pass of the loop only if it is.

Or, skip the nested loop entirely. Call `getCount()` on `all_adapter` and iterate over it. For each pass, retrieve the Nth item via `getItem()`. If that is not `null` and is an `instanceof` `MileageReceiptInterface`, do your `equals()` check.

Comment: i followed your instructions and i am almost correct now, please check my edited question. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: @AdrianOlar: I have no idea why you are doing `skip+=i`. `i` is the right position at this point, just scroll there.

Comment: you were right, works like a charm now, thank you so much for your directions.